# How to get my for loop working in R

Tags: r

I Have few variables `AGE` `ACT_TYPE GENDER` in my data frame. Instead of printing each of these factor variable's level distribution, I have used for loop to print the distribution. However nothing seems to be printing. Please let me know how to resolve the issue ..

---

```
   > str(combin)
         Classes ‘data.table’ and 'data.frame': 500000 obs. of  333 variables:
      $ CUSTOMER_ID               : int  385793 286891 108751 278651 23637 130723 5694 275523 163723 469852 ...
     $ ACT_TYPE                  : Factor w/ 2 levels "CSA","SA": 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 1 ...
     $ GENDER                    : Factor w/ 3 levels "","F","M": 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 ...
     $ LEGAL_ENTITY              : Factor w/ 7 levels "ASSOCIATION",..: 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3
```

---

```
 combin[, prop.table(table(GENDER))]
    GENDER
              F        M 
 0.000272 0.232436 0.767292 

  combin[, prop.table(table(ACT_TYPE))]
  ACT_TYPE
     CSA       SA 
  0.710686 0.289314
```

If I replace the above printing to the display with forloop, I don't see any o/p.
Please let me know where I am going wrong...

```
for(i in names(combin)) {
      combin[, prop.table(table(names(combin)[i]))]
}
```

Also suggest me how can I apply a condition in the for loop to only print the 
distribution only if it's a factor variable.

Comment: @G5W I think the other problem is the difference between `table(ACT_TYPE)` and `table("ACT_TYPE")`.

Comment: Try using the `print()` function inside the loop.

Answer (score 0):

You could use purrr to loop through each column of the data frame and return a list, where each item in the list corresponds to a column and the columns that are factors are the prop.tables

```
library(purrr)

#generate some random data like yours
mydf <- data_frame(
      id = sample(1:100, 10,replace = F)
    , ACT_TYPE = factor(sample(c("CSA", "SA"),10, replace = T))
    , GENDER = factor(sample(c("", "F", "M"), 10, replace = T))
 )

# use map_if to generate prop.tables when the column is a factor
map_if(mydf, ~class(.x) == "factor", ~prop.table(table(.x)) )
```

Comment: If you could mark it as the answer, that'd help keep things clean. Thanks!